Every cyclic quadrilateral is harmonic?
I am a high school student, olympiad focused, who can solve easy to mid level USAMO questions, say, around the questions from 2005.
I was reading projective transformations from EGMO (Evan Chen).
A theorem there states:

Any four points in the plane (no three of them collinear) can be sent
to any four other points (no three collinear) by a unique projective
transformation.

Also, it is given that a projective transformation preserves the cross ratio of concyclic points which are sent to concyclic points.
So, consider any cyclic quadrilateral. Use the theorem in the blocktext above to send it to a square. Now, the square is concyclic.
Therefore, cross-ratio(original quadrilateral) = cross-ratio(square) = -1.
Hence, every cyclic quadrilateral is harmonic. But this is clearly not true. Where did I go wrong?
Edit: The error in the argument is that the image of the circle need not be a circle, but rather, we can only say that it will be a conic, as @Intelligentipauca pointed out.
Can we say that if the image of the circle is a circle, and the image of the quadrilateral is a square, then the original quadrilateral must be a square, i.e, the projection must be a dilation?

"Also, it is given that a projective transformation preserves the cross ratio of concyclic points which are sent to concyclic points." This is not true: you must consider the cross ratio of the four points with respect to the trasnformed conic. And the transformed of a circle is not a circle, in general.

This is the para I was refering to. Page 184.  "Furthermore, projective transformations preserve the cross ratio of any four collinear points. Moreover, if four concyclic points are sent to four concyclic points, then the cross ratio of the quadrilaterals are the same." If this is wrong, could you please give me a link to a handout or smthng which is better?

@Lauren The cross-ratio is defined only for 4 collinear points. You might argue that there is a cross-ratio for 4 non-collinear points. However the vertices of a harmonic quadrilateral are points on the projective complex line $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ and this is where the cross-ratio is defined for what seem to be "non-collinear points" but no. It is not called the projective complex plane because $\mathbb{C}$ (without the hat) is an $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. 4 points in your reasoning are in fact collinear (on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$) that is where things gone wrong.

@DuongNgo since the complex line is a 'line', shouldn't any 4 points be collinear? could you give the condition for collinearity on the complex line or is it the determinant = 0 formula?

See Th. 9.3.2 on page 30 here: https://web.evanchen.cc/textbooks/tr011ey.pdf

@Lauren They lie on the projective complex line, so they are collinear (of course not in the common Euclidean sense).
When high school students use (or are taught to use) projective geometry tools to solve Euclidean geometry problems, they usually take them (the tools) for granted. To use those tools properly, one has to embed the usual Euclidean plane into the projective real plane or the projective complex line (these are not the same) because the use of those tools is not rigorous without the points at infinity.
